# How to plug in an implicit function into another function and evaluate in Mathematica?

Tags: functions, implicit

I am wondering how to do the following in Mathematica.

Say, we have an implicit function $y=f(x)$ defined by $F(x,y)=0$.

I would like to evaluate another function $G(x,y)$ at the implicit function $y=f(x)$ defined above.

To give you a concrete example, $F(x,y)=0$ is given by
$$
(x-0.5)\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)^{0.5}-x=(y-0.5)\left(\frac{y-1}{y}\right)^{0.5}-y,
$$ here $1<x<y$. This defines an implicit function $y=f(x)$.

I would like to evaluate the following function at $y=f(x)$:
$$
G(x, y)=\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)^{0.5}\left[(x-0.5)\ln\frac{x-1}{x}-1\right]-\left(\frac{y-1}{y}\right)^{0.5}\left[(y-0.5)\ln\frac{y-1}{y}-1\right]
$$.

How to implement this in Mathematica? Thanks.

Comment: It's (usually) hard if at least one of $F$ and $G$ are transcendental. If both are algebraic, there are tricks for doing this.

Comment: You are more likely to get a useful response if you provide a concrete example to work with.

Comment: Please see my updated post, with a concrete example. Thanks.

Comment: Writing $z^{0.5}$ is rarely a good idea in Mathematica. Better to write $\sqrt{z}$ as `Sqrt[z]` because it can make additional assumptions that the machine-precision exponent of 0.5 does not allow.

Comment: ^seconded. Equivalently, use `z^(1/2)` (which is the same as `Sqrt[z]`) or `z^(p/q)` in general; the problem is that mathematica distinguishes between `0.5` (machine precision by default) and `1/2` (which is kept as an exact fraction).

Answer (score 3):

The obvious solution is through [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html), which may not be possible for other choices of $F(x,y)$.

```
F[x_, y_] = ((x - 1/2) Sqrt[(x - 1)/x] - x) -
            ((y - 1/2) Sqrt[(y - 1)/y] - y);
```

We can see the different solution branches in a [contour plot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html):

```
ContourPlot[F[x, y] == 0, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

```
Solve[F[x, y] == 0, y]
(*    {{y -> x},
       {y -> (-2 - Sqrt[(-1 + x)/x] + 2 x + 2 Sqrt[(-1 + x)/x] x)/(-4 + 4 x)}}    *)

G[x_, y_] = Sqrt[(x - 1)/x] ((x - 1/2) Log[(x - 1)/x] - 1) -
            Sqrt[(y - 1)/y] ((y - 1/2) Log[(y - 1)/y] - 1);

Plot[G[x, (-2 - Sqrt[(-1 + x)/x] + 2 x + 2 Sqrt[(-1 + x)/x] x)/(-4 + 4 x)],
     {x, 1, 3}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "G(x,y(x))"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!